# Fetch requests on built node+react app responds with index.html content

Tags: node.js, reactjs, build

I've created a react app with node backend and recently ran the `npm run build` command on it.
when served, I noticed the fetch request sent from my frontend don't work properly and actually just respond with the index.html file in my frontend>public folder for no reason.
I'll try to add info that might be relevant.

In my package.json (the one that's in the frontend folder):

```
"proxy":"http://localhost:3000",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set PORT=3001 && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

In index.js (server side)

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3001',
    credentials: true,
}));
```

an example of a post definition on the server:

```
app.post("/user/login", (req, res) => {
  login(req, res)

});
```

and the request itself:

```
const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({ "email": email, "password": password }),
      credentials: 'include'

    };
    //HTTP://localhost:3000
    fetch(`/user/login`, requestOptions).then(response => {
      if (response.status == 200) {
        console.log(document.cookie.split("=")[1])
        setToken(document.cookie.split("=")[1]);
        console.log("here")

      }
      else {
        setError(true)
        response.json().then((data) => {
          setMessage(data.msg)
          console.log(data.msg)
        })
      }
    })
```

The request's status gives 200 and the respond is always the content of index.html . the request URL as shown on my browser is http://localhost:3000/user/login.

When I run the app with npm start and nodemon, everything works fine.
Only when I try to serve the build it stops working as it should.
Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Show your fetch request. Are you sure that you are using the correct path?

Comment: @Konrad  I'll edit the main post with the request